# What's the correct way to format long print statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, coding-style

I noticed that Visual Studio is changing how these long print statements are formatted and I'm not sure if it's good formatting or a bug. In the tutorials I'm watching they're being formatted differently. I just want to make sure that I'm teaching myself best practices so I'm not putting out sloppy code.

This is what the code looks like in the tutorial video and prior to having VSC auto format:

```
if tweet_length == max_length:
    print(f"Your tweet contains {tweet_length} characters, thats the max! if your tweet was any longer it wouldn't have worked!")
elif tweet_length < max_length:
    print(f"Your tweet contains {tweet_length}, you have a remaining {char_left} characters left to use.")
elif tweet_length > max_length:
    print(f"Your tweet contains {tweet_length}, you're over by {tweet_length - max_length} characters. Try something shorter!")
```

This is how VSC wants to format it:

```
if tweet_length == max_length:
    print(
        f"Your tweet contains {tweet_length} characters, thats the max! if your tweet was any longer it wouldn't have worked!")
elif tweet_length < max_length:
    print(
        f"Your tweet contains {tweet_length}, you have a remaining {char_left} characters left to use.")
elif tweet_length > max_length:
    print(
        f"Your tweet contains {tweet_length}, you're over by {tweet_length - max_length} characters. Try something shorter!")
```

Which one is considered best practice?

Comment: Formatting questions are judgment calls. Which formatting do you like better? If you like the first one better, do you want to hand format these lines or would you rather just accept its results even if they're suboptimal, in the name of consistency? There's no objective right answer. Opinion-based questions are, unfortunately, off-topic, so this will probably be closed.

Comment: FYI, the formatter in VS Code is configurable: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatting. You can select any of the supported formatters, _each one has its own style_ and its own set of configurations. You may have a preferred style but if that formatter doesn't support that style, then the question is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Look both are same just the placement of circle parentheses is different. It only depends upon the programmer. As some of the programmers are coming from java,C++ background, they are comfortable in following the VSC method, but many people uses the method as mentioned in tutorial video. So both are good. The execution time of both the commands will be same.